# Whitespace not passing addition assignment for HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to incrementally add letters to a `HTMLElement`, but whitespace (most spaces, some linebreaks) seem to disappear when I do this

For example:

```
let s = "f o o b a r";
let e = document.createElement('span');
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  // do some stuff
  e.innerText += s[i];
}

// e.innerText = "foobar"
```

I've stepped through the code and seen `e.innerText += " "` when `s[i] = " "`, but I can't figure out why it doesn't get added to `e`. My assumption is somehow the whitespace gets trimmed due to it being the last item, but I'm unsure how to stop this (short of setting `whitespace: pre`, but that also prevents linebreaks and seems overkill)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an HTML issue rather than a JavaScript issue. In HTML, whitespace in the source is collapsed to only display one space on the page. It was designed this way so that when HTML page authors could insert as many line breaks or indentation as they wanted for organisation without affecting the display.

In your case, since you want the white space to display, there are a few choices for how to work around this:

1. You could consider using a CSS directive like `white-space: pre-wrap` which [preserves spaces while still allowing text to flow across lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).
2. Rather than inserting spaces, you could insert [non-breaking space characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), which are never collapsed.
3. Since the `innerText` [property is "aware of the rendered appearance of the text", the value of the property in JavaScript will reflect how spaces are treated in the DOM.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) So if whitespaces are collapsed, they will also be removed from the value of `innerText`. You can avoid this by using the standard `textContent` property instead.

To learn more, you can read more about the fundamentals of [whitespace collapsing on MDN here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace)

If this doesn't answer your question, I recommend you add a screenshot of what you expected vs what you got to your original question to help people provide more accurate answers.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. I find if I set `white-space: pre`, this almost solves the issue. I still seem to be dropping some newlines if they are between tags for some reason

Comment: @user760900 I have edited my answer to add list item 3 to my post, please take a look at it and the documentation it links to to see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use   t.textContent  += s[i];

InnerText represents only the visible text content of an element and does not include any whitespace or HTML tags.

Comment: This seems to remove all whitespace unless I add `white-space: pre`, which then completely fixes the problem of dropping some whitespace. Any idea why?

Comment: let e = document.getElementById('test');
let s = "f o o b a r";
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  // do some stuff
  e.textContent += s[i];
}

// e.textContent = "f o o b a r"